# Facebook Social Discovery - programmatic post to specific user's wall?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I trigger a programmatic post to a specific person's Facebook wall so that it looks like this (but replace GO TRY IT ON with my app):

[image]

I do not want this to be a generic post to the world.  I want this targeted to the specific user's wall whom I specify.  I want to include a specific message.  I already have social discovery for my app enabled (meaning that I can see my app when I search facebook on my iPhone, and I see it in my list of apps such that I can tap the row and launch my app from facebook).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to familiarize yourself with the concept of the Open Graph -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

*product* is obviously an **object** defined in that apps open graph settings, and *suggesting* is an **action** that can be undertaken with products.

So what you've shown us in this picture is not a normal *post*, it's the publication message of an Open Graph action.
But I'm not aware of any simple way to make this publication visible only to one user. The general visibility is set by the user in the auth dialog for your app. I don't know if there's a way to further restrict visibility for a single action publication, maybe by dynamically creating a friendlist with only that one user in it or something …